# JS - How to remove last four chars from HTML-span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

Hello I use SharePoint Designer. Solution is html. I have a date and  want to remove year from span...

**This is my code:**

```
<div class="event-date">
<span>
    <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="8336201e-40ba-494c-95b7-42d9096709f6" runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
    <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
</span>
```

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `$('div.event-date span:first').text(function(i,v){ return v.slice(0, -4); });`

Comment: Could you show the actual HTML output please. We can't know where to remove the value from without it.

Comment: @Gohyu : comment updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
var date = $('div.event-date').find('span').text();
    date = date.slice(0, -5);

example,
var date = "01-07-2016";
    date = str.slice(0,-5);
```

Comment: thid will give date as 2016 , you should give start index as well date.slice(0,-4)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, ans has been modified. Thanks @Deep

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery use **[`text()` method with callback](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** to update based on the old content. Use **[`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method to get string where last 4 characters are removed.

```
$('div.event-date span:first').text(function(i,v){ 
  return v.slice(0, -4); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.event-date span:first').text(function(i, v) {
      return v.slice(0, -4);
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="event-date">
  <span>1.1.2016</span>
</div>
```

---

With pure JavaScript

```
var span = document.querySelector('div.event-date span');
span.textContent = span.textContent.slice(0, -4);
```

```html
<div class="event-date">
  <span>1.1.2016</span>
</div>
<script>
  var span = document.querySelector('div.event-date span');
  span.textContent = span.textContent.slice(0, -4);
</script>
```

Comment: Where i paste this in my code, Sorry but i'm beginner 8:(

Comment: @Gohyu : check the snippet